# Cobol binary file reading

Tags: java, binary, cobol

I have a binary file written by a COBOL application. The document about this binary file stating that the first 4 byes is the sizeof upcoming record. Out of 4 byes, 1st and 2nd bytes are the binary represcentaion of the record length and next 2 byes are null values(reserved). This is the only input that I have.  How can I read into a java integer. Should I read the first 4 byes or only 2 byes for reading into java integer.  I am confused because in java integer is of 4 byes.

Is it is possible to read binary writen from COBOL application in to java variables.

Comment: Leaving aside that, how are you going to know what the data represents (rather than the RDW, Record Descriptor Word, which is what you are describing)? If you have a "copybook" or a "record layout" please show it. The record-length part of the RDW is a two-byte binary maximum value 32756. It is followed by two bytes, which you can ignore, and then the first byte of the data. The record-length (first two bytes) are length of RDW+length of data. Your data is coming from an IBM Mainframe? Possibly an IBM Midrange? EBCDIC may be involved, which is why the record-layout is important to see.

Comment: Data is coming from base24. The file is binary file and is of 10 gb side.  About that 2 bytes, is it possible to read only the 2 bytes and conver into integer using java?. How a binary file written by one programing language can be parsed in another.

Comment: Consider if a programing language keeping its 4 byes of integer data from right to left( the bits are written from right to left.). If it is parsed by the same programing language then it can parse it. If the same is parsed using java, we might ended up in diffrent integer value, since java will read 4 bytes from left to right.

Comment: @Jobs Read the bytes then swap the order so that java understands it correctly.  I don't think there is a built in way to read little endian data in java, but you can probably find a library to do it.  If not writing it yourself shouldn't be too difficult to get working.

Answer (score 0):

You could read it in using a java short, which is a 16-bit integer, or you could read the first four bytes into an integer and shift right 16.